# Maximum update depth exceeded error in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to update state based on value selected from dropdown and fetching from backend but it's falling in loop and reaching maximum depth.

```
export function something(){
const [getState, setState] = useMergeState({
    isValue: false,
    initialState: {
      a: '',
      b: '',
      c: '',
      d: ''
    }
})

const fetchData = () => {
   apiCall().then(res => {
   if(res.status === 200){
     setState({
       initialState: {
         ...initialState,
         d:response.data
       }  
     })
   }
})
}

useEffect(() => {
 if(getState.isValue) fetchData()
})

const renderView = (props) => {
let {values} = props;
values.something === 'xyz' && setState({isValue: true})
return(
   <Dropdown>
   <Dropdown>
)}

return(
   <Formik initialValue={getState.initialState} render={renderView}/>
)}
```

In this code I am trying to setState based on the input selected, if input `selected === 'xyz'` then it will setState as true and if isValue's value is true then it will hit api to get some data and store it in the state. The issue is once I try to set the state in **renderView** it falls into infinity loop. I am unable to get the values selected anywhere else.

Thank you

Comment: u set `isValue` to `true`, when u set it to false again ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fetchData = () => {
   apiCall().then(res => {
   if(res.status === 200){
     setState({
      isValue: false, // Changes here
       initialState: {
         ...initialState,
         d:response.data
       }  
     })
   }
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Updated Answer by changing some logic here, I don't see any purpose for the `isValue` state, so i removed it. If u think u still need `isValue` please describe it.

```js
export function something(){
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState({
    a: '',
    b: '',
    c: '',
    d: ''
  })
  
  const fetchData = () -> {
    apiCall().then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setInitialState({ ...initialState, d: response.data })
      }
    })
  }
  
  const renderView = props => {
  
    // If you are going to fetch on the first time,
    useEffect(fetchData, [])
    
    // If you are looking to fetch everytimes the values update
    useEffect(fetchData, [props.values])
    
    return (
      <Dropdown>
    )
  }

return(
   <Formik initialValue={getState.initialState} render={renderView}/>
)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not working as it goes to renderView again and see the `values.something === 'xyz'` and set it to isValue to true again and goes into infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

### Clean code - separate things

my suggest do like that (the code):

It is more clear and understandable.

```
export function something() {
  const initState = { a: '', b: '', c: '', d: '' };

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
  const [isValue, setIsValue] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await apiCall();
    if (res.status === 200) setState({ ...state, d: res.data });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isValue) fetchData();
  })

  const renderView = ({ values }) => {
    if (values.something === 'xyz') setIsValue(true);
    return <Dropdown></Dropdown>
  }

  return (
    <Formik initialValue={initState} render={renderView} />
  )
}
```

It can be more clear, like if the key of the initState would not be a,b,c,d. and be more meaningful names.

For your problem it occurs because you can not `return <Dropdown></Dropdown>` because it is a function that `Formik` can active but do not response to it, this statement should remove. and you should pass the Formik component the `isValue` and inside render Dropdown conditionally by the `isValue` value.

Comment: Thank you @Omer for the refactor you suggested will do that, But it doesn't help me with the problem

Comment: sorry, I forgot it, for your problem it occurs because you can not `return <Dropdown></Dropdown>` because it is a function that `Formik` can active but do not response to it, this statement should remove. and you should pass the Formik component the `isValue` and inside render Dropdown conditionally by the `isValue` value.